# tableView never shows up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been at this for some time now. I can not get my tableView to appear. I think it has something to do with the fact that it is being presented as `didMove(toParent)`

I am trying to create a page that allows you to add a new Card to the profile. Every time I write it programmatically or use storyboard it crashes as it `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.`

Here is the view Controller that is presenting the Side Menu

```
import Foundation
import SideMenu
import FirebaseAuth
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI



class BeginViewController: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   private var sideMenu: SideMenuNavigationController?
   
   struct customData {
       var title: String
       var image: UIImage
   }
   
   let data = [
       customData(title: "NottingHill", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "norali-nayla-SAhImiWmFaw-unsplash")),
       customData(title: "Southall", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "alistair-macrobert-8wMflrTLm2g-unsplash")),
       customData(title: "Tower Hill", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "peregrine-communications-0OLnnZWg860-unsplash")),
       customData(title: "Mansion House", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "adam-birkett-cndNklOnHO4-unsplash")),
       customData(title: "Westminster", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "simon-mumenthaler-NykjYbCW6Z0-unsplash")),
       customData(title: "London Bridge", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hert-niks-CjouXgWrTRk-unsplash"))
       
   
   
   ]
   
   struct Constants {
       static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15.0 }

 
           
   let manager = CLLocationManager()
       
   
           private let ProfileController = ProfileViewController()
           private let MyBookingsController = MyBookingsViewController()
           private let WalletController = WalletViewController()
           private let FAQController = FAQViewController()
           private let SettingsController = SettingsViewController()
           
   

   
   @IBOutlet weak var StoreButton: UIButton!
   
   @IBOutlet weak var DeliverButton: UIButton!
   
   @IBOutlet weak var AirportButton: UIButton!
   
   @IBOutlet weak var HotelsButton: UIButton!
   
   
   
   fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
       let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
       cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       cv.register(customCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
       return cv
   }()

   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()
               
              // buttons
       StoreButton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
       StoreButton.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
       StoreButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
       StoreButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       StoreButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
               
               DeliverButton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
               DeliverButton.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
               DeliverButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
               DeliverButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
               DeliverButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5

               AirportButton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
               AirportButton.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
               AirportButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
               AirportButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
               AirportButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5

               HotelsButton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
               HotelsButton.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
               HotelsButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
               HotelsButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
               HotelsButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
       
               //CollectionViewNearbyPlaces
               view.addSubview(collectionView)
               collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
               collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 450).isActive = true
               collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
               collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                   collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
       
               collectionView.delegate = self
               collectionView.dataSource = self

               // title
               title = "handl"
               //background
              
               let menu = MenuController(with: [ "Home", "Profile", "My Bookings",
                                                "Wallet",
                                                "FAQ","Settings"])
               menu.delegate = self
               sideMenu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: menu)
               sideMenu?.leftSide = true
               sideMenu?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
               SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = sideMenu
               SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: view)

               addChildControllers()
               
            
             
           }
   
           override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
               super.viewDidAppear(animated)
               manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
               manager.delegate = self
               manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
               manager.startUpdatingLocation()
               handleNotAuthenticated()
               
         
   
   
           }
           private func addChildControllers() {
               addChild(ProfileController)
               addChild(MyBookingsController)
               addChild(WalletController)
               addChild(FAQController)
               addChild(SettingsController)
               view.addSubview(ProfileController.view)
               view.addSubview(MyBookingsController.view)
               view.addSubview(WalletController.view)
               view.addSubview(FAQController.view)
               view.addSubview(SettingsController.view)
               ProfileController.view.frame = view.bounds
               MyBookingsController.view.frame = view.bounds
               WalletController.view.frame = view.bounds
               FAQController.view.frame = view.bounds
               SettingsController.view.frame = view.bounds
               
               ProfileController.didMove(toParent: self)
               MyBookingsController.didMove(toParent: self)
               WalletController.didMove(toParent: self)
               FAQController.didMove(toParent: self)
               SettingsController.didMove(toParent: self)
               
               
               ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
               MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
               WalletController.view.isHidden = true
               FAQController.view.isHidden = true
               SettingsController.view.isHidden = true

               }

               @IBAction func SideMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
               present(sideMenu!, animated: true)

               }

           func didSelectMenuItem(named: String) {
               sideMenu?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
                   
                   
                   self?.title = named
                   
                   if named == "Home" {
                   
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       
                   }
                   
                   if named == "Profile" {
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = false
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       
                   }
                   
                   if named == "My Bookings" {
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = false
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = true
                   }
                   else if named == "Wallet" {
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = false
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = true
                   }
                   else if named == "FAQ" {
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = false
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = true
                   }
                   else if named == "Settings" {
                       self?.ProfileController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.MyBookingsController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.WalletController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.FAQController.view.isHidden = true
                       self?.SettingsController.view.isHidden = false
                   }
               
               })
           
           }

 
   }



extension BeginViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
   
   
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
   }
   
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return data.count
       
   }

   
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
       cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
       return cell
   }
   
   class customCell: UICollectionViewCell {
       
       var data: customData? {
           didSet {
               guard let data = data else { return }
               bg.image = data.image
               
           }
       }
       
       fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
           let iv = UIImageView()
           iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "adam-birkett-cndNklOnHO4-unsplash")
           iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
           iv.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
           iv.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
           iv.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
           iv.layer.shadowRadius = 10
           iv.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: iv.bounds).cgPath
           iv.layer.shouldRasterize = false
           iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
           iv.clipsToBounds = true
          
           
          
           return iv
       }()
       
       override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
       
           contentView.addSubview(bg)
           bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
           bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
           bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
           bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
           
   }
       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
       
   }
   
  
//if user is not logged in show login


private func handleNotAuthenticated() {
   //check auth status
if  Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
   //show log in screen
   let loginVC = LoginViewController()
   loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   present(loginVC, animated: false)
   
       }
}

}
```

and Here is the viewController I am trying to present a tableView on. It comes up with a white screen, but no tableView. Nor are my navigation items showing. Even when written programmatically.

```
import UIKit

class WalletViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var addNewCard = [String]()
    
    let button = UIButton()

    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        addTable()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "RED")
        button.setTitle("Add New Card", for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "yellow-2")
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "RED"), for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 700, width: 350, height: 50)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapAddButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        if !UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "setup") {
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "setup")
            UserDefaults().set(0, forKey: "count")
            
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add New Card", style: .plain, target: self,
            action: #selector(didTapAdd))
            
        }
    }
    
    func updateCard() {
        
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        
        for x in 0..<count {
            
            if let addCard = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "addCard\(x+1)") as? String {
               addNewCard.append(addCard)
           }
        }
    
    }
        

    
    func addTable() {
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "addCard")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapAdd() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addCard") as! addCardViewController
        vc.update = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateCard()
        }
}
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapAddButton() {
        let rootVC = addCardViewController()
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(navVC, animated: true)
            
        }
}


extension WalletViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
     
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}


extension WalletViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let add = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCard", for: indexPath)
        add.textLabel?.text = addNewCard[indexPath.row]
        return add
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addNewCard.count
    }

    
}
```

Comment: "it crashes as it Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" It's a well known error. Which line exactly causes the crash? Try to find which one first.

Comment: An „implicitly unwrapped optional“ is normally a `var` declared with an exclamation mark that you guarantee to be not `nil` during run time, e.g. in your statement `@IBOutlet weak var StoreButton: UIButton! `. 
I assume that all your `@IBOutlet` are connected to the corresponding elements in the storyboard. What is not clear from your code is if the statement `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addCard")` indeed instantiates a view controller. It might be that `storyboard` is `nil`, or there is no view controller named `addCard`.

Comment: To comply@ReinhardMänner , check the the view controller declared in storyboard is of correct type addCardViewController (not UIViewCintroller)

Comment: the implicitly unwrapped error comes on the first line of the tableView, in viewDidLoad. Be it, registering the cell, delegate or data source. I have changed their order and results are the same. So it could be that the tableView, is finding nil somewhere I just dont know where. It is storyboarded and connected, then I have tried this programmatically also.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, appreciate it but yeah there is a storyboard, and the class is set correctly also.

Comment: I have tried this on another side Menu and I get the same results. I think it could be because of the way the sideMenu is set up to navigate?